# Get first parent key of value from Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to get the first parent key of value from Multidimensional Array in PHP

**Sample Code :**

```
$arr = array(
    "a" => array("1"=>"!","2"=>"@","3"=>"#"),
    "b" => array("4"=>"$","5"=>"%","6"=>"^"),
    "c" => array("7"=>"&","8"=>"*","9"=>"(")
);

echo array_search("%",$arr);
```

**Require Output:**
b

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You may be closer to the solution that you expect

Comment: **No,**  I get Solution from AbraCadaver's Answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array returning only the array(s) that contain what you are searching for and get the key:

```
echo key(array_filter($arr, function($v) { return array_search("%", $v); }));
```

Obviously if it is found in more than one array you will have to decide which key you want.  The above will give you the first key.